# CFM files on server hacked, any insight on what might be going on?

Tags: security, coldfusion

Discovered some hacked CFM files on my server, decrypted them, and here is what I have found (among many others, but this one seems substantial). I was wondering if anyone has some insight into the implications of the hack, or maybe has seen something similar?

http://pastebin.com/RJySHvQv

Comment: This is better suited for Serverfault

Comment: What version of CF do you have?

Answer (score 11):

That's a common web shell uploaded by hackers to exploit your server.  Your server is most likely not current on CF patches and has the /CFIDE/administrator directory publicly available (against best practice)

- Take your server offline.
- Do not try to clean, it needs to be rebuilt from scratch
- All code, and CF settings need to be audited
- Assume everything in your database has been stolen and notify customers
- Hire a CF company company to help you reconfigure your servers securely.  There are many for you to choose from. I work for one and would be happy to help if you wish.

Comment: In addition to Brad's suggestion, Check your site with http://hackmycf.com/ and then report it to psirt@adobe.com, if needed.

Comment: +1 Anit.  Hack My CF is an excellent tool.